# Order by date in different directions

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, sql-order-by

I have a booking system and a page showing a user's bookings - past and future.

I want to order the bookings with future bookings first, ordered with the next session at the top (asc), then past bookings, beginning with the latest session (desc).

I currently have this:

```
from sess in Sessions
    orderby sess.SessionDate < DateTime.Now.Date, sess.SessionDate
    select sess
```

But that gives both sets in asc order. Any way to conditionally sort after the first order by clause?

I've also considered using `IQueryable<T>.Concat`. Would that be the way to go? I assume that results in a Union of some sort, but can I guarantee it would keep the sort order for both sets?

e.g. results: 
Sessions

```
2015-03-01 - some class
2015-03-15 - a different class
2015-04-10 - also a class
(the split between past and future sessions)
2014-12-22 - some tutorial
2014-11-15 - some sort of class
2014-10-08 - some other class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator combined with a [DateDiff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487052(v=vs.110).aspx) function for the second order by. This will allow you to swap `DateTime.Now` and your `SessionDate`

```
let isSessionDateLessThanNow = sess.SessionDate < DateTime.Now
orderby isSessionDateLessThanNow, 
        isSessionDateLessThanNow ? 
           SqlFunctions.DateDiff("s", sess.SessionDate, DateTime.Now) :
           SqlFunctions.DateDiff("s", DateTime.Now, sess.SessionDate)
```

Comment: Can you go into more detail about your answer.  I'm looking at it and still don't know "what just happened".  I just know it looks awesome.

Comment: @granadaCoder - the first `order by`  will evaluate to `false` for future dates, so they will be placed before the past dates. Second `order by` is just ordering by the closest to `DateTime.Now`, but you need to swap the parameters at the _border_ otherwise you would start getting negative numbers

Comment: I 'see it' now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about split it into two separate queries, first one with future sessions order by session date ascending. add them to a list. an then another query with past sessions order by session date descending. add them to the same list.

i don't see any chance to solve this i one query without any mess.